# Oracle Advanced Queue Listen .Net WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, oracle-aq

I'm trying to execute the method Listen in Oracle AQ , but I have 2 situations that happens:

1) When I connect on the queue, and already has message in the queue, I can Dequeue messages normally, but when I finish to dequeue, and stop at Listen method, and then Enqueue new message, the my Listen methods doesn't unblock, like it don't see that have a new message in queue.

2) When I connect on the queue, and don't have messages, I try to execute Listen method, but it catch a Oracle Exception:

> ORA25306 - Cannot connect to buffered queue's owner instance.

My queue is single-consumer, in my method Listen I don't specified consumer.
I tried to solve using the ORA-25306 from oracle, but don't.

Comment: Additional, my queue was work until last Friday, but in this Tuesday morning it stop.